# Span leaks outside of its parent elements

Tags: css

Span tags leak outside of its direct parent and all other wrapping parents too. [Take a look at this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3mgbvnp/).

I've tried `display`, `overflow` and other properties but I can't figure this out. It just keeps leaking out.

**How to fix that?**

```css
.tag {
  padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap; /* prevent splitting spans */
}

.tag-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="tag-wrapper">
    <span class="tag">tag 1</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 2</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 3</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 4</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 5</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 6</span>
    <span class="tag">tag 7</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried to find an answer but it seems that I don't know how to phrase this question. Im familiar with **collapsing margins** and it seems to be a different problem.

Comment: Using `display:inline-block` to your `.tag` class will fix your issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for `display: inline-block;`.

`<span>` elements by nature are an *inline* element, so their effective height is actually based on their content, rather than their bounding box. By making it behave as a `block` element, you should achieve your desired effect.

[**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/g3mgbvnp/1/) is an updated version of your fiddle, and here is the updated `tag` CSS:

```
.tag {
  padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  white-space: nowrap; /* prevent splitting spans */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `display: inline-block` in `.tag`. Checkout the updated **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3mgbvnp/2/)**

Just like:

```
.tag {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In the future, make sure to read all other answers before posting your own.

Comment: @Santi I was in the middle of writing my answer, so I didn't able to see any answer. That's not fair. Will keep in mind from now on.

Comment: Not an issue, just a friendly reminder. I didn't report it or downvote it for that reason exactly, I've done the same thing.